# :first-child selector not working on li (list item)

Tags: html, css, sass

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/iqbal98/rxp0dxm9/

**Issue:** Select first instance of the class `search-result-group-posts`

In this case `ul` has many `li` or called `.search-result-item` too, but specifically on

```
li.search-result-item.search-result-group-posts
```

I want the first of this `li`'s to have a different `background-color` and a `margin-left`

This is what I want: https://jsfiddle.net/iqbal98/rxp0dxm9/1/ (html inline css added)

PD:

- look at `/*DOES NOT WORK*/` comment section to quickly see the problem
- I'm using Sass and the `:first-child` selector is used this way: `&:first-child`. I also tried in a separated way (without the "&")

```css
li.search-result-group[data-search-group=posts]{
        border-bottom-width:0;
      }
      .search-result-group-posts:first-child{
        margin-left:10%;/*DOES NOT WORK*/
        background-color:red;/*DOES NOT WORK*/
      }
      li.search-result-item.search-result-group-posts{
        position:relative;
        border:1px solid brown;
        display:inline-block!important;
        width:29.478%;
        border-radius:4px;
        margin:0 5px;
        .search-result-post-up{
          font-size:16px!important;
          border-radius: 10px;
          padding:4px;
          .search-result-post-title{
            margin-left:3%;
            font-size:110%!important;
          }
          .search-result-post-content{
            white-space:normal!important;
            margin:.3% 2% .7% 2%;
            font-size: 70%!important;
            text-align:justify;
          }
        }
      }
```

```html
<ul class="search-result-list" style="height: 755.383px;">
  <li class="search-result-group" data-search-group="posts">Posts<span class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></span></li>
  <li class="search-result-item search-result-group-posts">
    <div class="search-result-post-up">
      <a href="#!">
        <span class="search-result-post-title">Lorem Ipsum</span>
        <p class="search-result-post-content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eget egestas est, consequat consequat nibh.
        </p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="search-result-item search-result-group-posts">
    <div class="search-result-post-up">
      <a href="#!">
        <span class="search-result-post-title">Lorem Ipsum</span>
        <p class="search-result-post-content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eget egestas est, consequat consequat nibh.
        </p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="search-result-item search-result-group-posts">
    <div class="search-result-post-up">
      <a href="#!">
        <span class="search-result-post-title">Lorem ipsum</span>
        <p class="search-result-post-content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eget egestas est, consequat consequat nibh.
        </p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="search-result-group" data-search-group="categories">Categories</li>
  <li class="search-result-item search-result-group-categories">category-1</li>
  <li class="search-result-item search-result-group-categoies">category-2</li>
  <li class="search-result-group" data-search-group="user-favorites">Favorites</li>
  <li class="search-result-item search-result-group-user-favorites">favorite-1</li>
  <li class="search-result-item search-result-group-user-favorites">favorite-2</li>
  <li class="search-result-item search-result-group-user-favorites">favorite-3</li>
  <li class="search-result-group" data-search-group="keywords">Keywords</li>
  <li class="search-result-item search-result-group-keywords">keyword-1</li>
  <li class="search-result-item search-result-group-keywords">keyword-2</li>
  <li class="search-result-item search-result-group-keywords">keyword-3</li>
  <li class="search-result-item search-result-group-keywords">keyword-4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `search-result-group-posts` is not the first child; there is the `Posts` `<li>` that comes first

Comment: One problem is that you're trying to use SCSS without specifying that in the Fiddle.

Comment: @kittykittybangbang's answer is why it isn't working. That element isn't the "first child" of it's parent - it's the first instance of that class. Those are 2 different things.

Comment: using SCSS on jsfiddle just adds some styles to the result

Comment: @Michael Coker how can I select the first instance of a class? I tried both `first-of-type` and `first-child`

Comment: Here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_firstchild is selecting first instance of `p` (inside the `body`). Am I wrong?

Comment: @iqbal_cs you need to give it a class or find some sort of workaround, there isn't a `:first-of-class` selector yet in CSS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class

Comment: Please post your "*[mcve]*" code (including the relevant HTML) in your question, otherwise if, or when, JS Fiddle (or any other external site) fails this question will become useless to future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who want to **select the first instance of a class**, this is the syntax:

```
.the-class{
    background-color: red; /*APPLY TO ALL*/
}
.the-class ~ .the-class {
    background-color: none; /*CANCEL TO SIBLINGS*/
}
```

In my case, I added this above all the SCSS code in the initial jsfiddle:

```
.search-result-group-posts{
    background-color: red;
}
.search-result-group-posts ~ .search-result-group-posts {
    background-color: none;
}
```

Good lesson learned today...